# PHP escape SQL Query algorithm

Tags: php, sql-server, escaping

I'm currently working with PHP 5.4.x and SQL Server 7 and I'm having TONS of issues with the PDO object for the ODBC Driver (Which is the only one that works on Sql Server 7), Statements throw errors everywhere ....

I finally got it working using PDO::query() method, BUT I need to escape the Input .... And PDO::quote IS NOT WORKING, I red the Documentation on [php pdo docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) about PDO and it says that PDO::quote is Not well implemented on PDO_ODBC, which might explain why im getting errors.

For Example: this

```
$escapedString = $pdoObject->quote($myQueryString);
```

returns False, it does not return the escaped string.

That been said,

Do you know a good way to escape input to prevent SQL INJECTION???

PS: Due to driver issues (old tech) I CANNOT Trust in SQL Statements, so is not an option.

Any ideas??

EDIT:

For Example. This does not work

`getQueryFromFile` is only retrieving a query from a file.

and `SqlServerPdo` is just a wrapper class I wrote over the PHP PDO so I get the connection as a Singleton

For the Record, the query actually WORKS, it has been tested on the Sql Server Engine

```
$conn = SqlServerPdo::connect();

$query = SqlServerPdo::getQueryFromFile('STUDENTS_FIND');

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);

$statement->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);}

$statement->execute();
```

This throws the error:

```
text is incompatible with int (SQLExecute[206] at ext\pdo_odbc\odbc_stmt.c:133)
```

It seems as if the statement is treating the :id param as a text, not as an INT.

bindValue returns the same error

Comment: So wait, are you saying that using prepared statements don't work?

Comment: nope, I'm having trouble binding the Parameters, I did a research online and apparently the PDO object for odbc is poorly implemented and it doesnt bind the values with the correct type, so Sql Server rejects the execution of the query

Comment: Can we see the full prepared statement? May be able to help with that.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44643  ... here is the explanation of why it doesnt work

Comment: ok, I'll edit the post in a sec

Comment: there, i posted an example

Comment: The actual query as well as the table definition would be helpful.

Comment: I dont actually have access to the query, I only develop the php backend, and I execute the queries according to the parameters my colleagues give me

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Nope, I tried everything that post said, and still can not make Statements work :P on odbc driver